# Vue js dynamically render router link path

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm struggling to find a way to render the path of the router-link dynamically, for example with the *test* variable. I'm trying to bind `:to` but unsuccessfully. I don't know if I can use the ternary operator in the binding as shown below:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-link
       :to="{ test ? '/success' : '/fail' }"
       tag="button"
       class="btn-next">
       <span class="btn-text">BUTTON</span>
    </router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script> 
export default {
  // ...
  data: function() {
    return {
      test: false
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is close (you don't need the curly brackets). It should look like this:

```
<router-link :to="test ? '/success' : '/fail'">
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/7mlqnjyq6j)